# Setting the baud rate for USART in STM32 microcontroller

Tags: serial-port, stm32, uart

Why do we need to calculate the baud rate using the following formula?

baud = f<sub>CK</sub> / (16*USARTDIV)

I mean, why can't we write 9600 or any other desired baud rate value directly in USART_BRR register? Why do we need to perform this calculation first? What are we calculating here anyway?

Answer (score 4):

You can't just write your desired baud rate into a register as the processor doesn't know how fast the clock is to that peripheral, so it wouldn't be able to set up dividers correctly.

It would be possible to make a USART that you could tell a baud rate too, but it would require extra complexity and would still need to know how fast its clock is.

Answer (score 3):

You are not configuring software, but **hardware**. That means, the bits you set are (more or less) directly connected to clock dividers which control the baud rate of the UART module.

As an example, you have to use f<sub>CK</sub> in your calculation. Imagine the UART module would have to calculate f<sub>CK</sub> by itself. The problem is, f<sub>CK</sub> is the result of all used clock dividers and not configured centrally. The effort to calculate f<sub>CK</sub> **in hardware** would just be disproportionate (effort = costs). It's just much easier to let the user calculate it.